# Windows Azure Cors for CDN not working

Tags: azure, cors, cdn, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I configured my blobstorage to support CORS requests. However on my blog it is still giving me errors for fonts retrieved from my CDN.

`Font from origin 'http://cdn.marcofranssen.nl' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://marcofranssen.nl' is therefore not allowed access.`

I used following code for enabling CORS on my blob storage using a simple console app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var creds = new StorageCredentials("myAccountName", "myKeyValue");
        var csa = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, true);
        ConfigureCors(csa);
    }

    private static void ConfigureCors(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount)
    {
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();

        var cors = new CorsRule();

        cors.AllowedHeaders.Add("*");
        cors.ExposedHeaders.Add("*");
        cors.AllowedOrigins.Add("*");
        cors.AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Options | CorsHttpMethods.Get;
        cors.MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600;

        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(cors);
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
    }
}
```

By debugging on the last line I see the properties/cors is applied successfully. There is one CORS rule in my properties...

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Looking at the comments here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx, it seems it is not possible today (please see the last comment which was posted just a week ago).

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that part... Seems the CDN is stripping the CORS Headers and in my case also the caching headers of my files. The CDN stuff still needs a lot of work to be a real and proper CDN.